# git でフォルダ (ファイル) ごとにマージストラテジーの使い分けはできるか？

Tags: git

git で、フォルダごとに異なったマージストラテジーを利用しながらマージを行いたくなりました。

これは、実現できますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下のページで説明されている通り、.git/info/attributesファイル または .gitattributesファイル に設定することができます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

フォルダごとに設定する場合、上記ファイルに

```
[パス]/* merge=[マージストラテジー]
```

と記載します。

例えば、 hoge フォルダ配下のファイルに oursストラテジーを適用する場合、

```
hoge/* merge=ours
```

と記載します。

サブフォルダにも同じストラテジーを適用したい場合、

```
[パス]/** merge=[マージストラテジー]
```

と、記載すればOKのようです。

ちなみに上のページの回答にあるとおり、マージストラテジーの中にはデフォルトで無効になっているものがあるようなのでご注意ください。